# How to convert a static code (reading 1 file) to a loop (reading several files)

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to convert the static code below (reading only X-90.vtu file) to a loop (reading a list of *.vtu files from a directory). And obviously, it would generate several output files (an output for each *.vtu file). I am not an expert in development. any help from your side will be appreciated.

```
import meshio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    mesh = meshio.read("X-90.vtu")
    Sn = mesh.point_data['Sn']
    coordinates = mesh.points
    data = np.zeros((len(coordinates),4))
    data[:,:3] = coordinates
    data[:,3:4] = Sn
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X','Y','Z','Sn'],dtype=float)
    del Sn, mesh, data, coordinates
    
    
    ####### Average Gas Saturation #####
    gas_saturation = dataframe[dataframe['Sn'] > 0].groupby(['Y'])['Sn'].mean()
    gas_saturation.name = 'Sn (average on X)'
    
    plt.figure(0), plt.plot(gas_saturation.values, gas_saturation.index)
    plt.xlabel('Average Gas Saturation'), plt.ylabel('Depth (m)'), plt.grid()
    gas_saturation.to_csv('gas_saturation_data.txt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows a loop to walk over all files in the current directory. When a file ends on `.vtu` your code is executed. The `cnt` is used to output your data in separate files.

```
import os
cnt = 0
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".vtu"):
        mesh = meshio.read(file)
        # your code between these files
        gas_saturation.to_csv(f'gas_saturation_data_{cnt}.txt')
        cnt += 1
```

Comment: It works. Thank you.
I'd have one more question, what do these three lines below mean?
    data = np.zeros((len(coordinates), 4))
    data[:, :3] = coordinates
    data[:, 3:4] = Sn

Comment: You can look up the documentation for numpy zeros, that's a good way to learn about it https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html. For the second part, look up numpy 2d array slicing.